# How can I make sure that my npm module methods are visible in Auto-Complete (intellisense)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, npm

I have a module that is going to be exported to npm to be used in other projects and for others that could use it to enjoy the library as well.

The code works, if you know the methods and properties you can call them and they work.

However (in my case) Intellisense isn't picking them up whereas other npm modules do (i.e. ws)

I published the module/library to npm and installed it into my new project (https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0BPU.png for reference on the intellisense I am seeing)

Now my question is as follows, am I missing a step in order to get this to work so that developers see the available methods and properties?

I've tried looking into other modules and see how they did it, but from what I can tell this should show up in intellisense, but it doesn't...

```
'use strict';

class ParkDS {
    constructor() {
       var c = require('./Config/Config');
       var d = require('./DataSource/DataSource'));

       this.config = new c();
       this.datasource = new d();
       this.certificate = {
           Cert: "",
           Key: ""
       };

    }

    /**
     * @returns {Object}
     * @public
     * */
    get Config() {
        return this.config;
    }

    /**
     * @returns {Object}
     * @public
     * */
    get DataSource() {
        return this.datasource
    }

    /**
     * @returns {Object}
     * @public
     * */
    get Certificate() {
        return this.certificate;
    }

    /**
     * @public
     * */
    Test() {
        console.log("test");
    }    

    /**
     * @public
     * */
    Start() {
       // Code to start all services
    }

    /**
     * @public
     * */
    Stop() {
      // Code to stop all services

    }
}

module.exports = ParkDS;
```

I expect the intellisense to show Config, DataSource, and Cerfificate as Properties, and Test, Start, Stop as Methods